# Autoresize the Webform

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me how to autoresize the the Web form when GridView gets longer because it covers the label below the gridview.
Thanks in Advance:D

Answer (score 1):

You are using CSS `position:` or `z-index:` somewhere. Don't do that and your elements won't overlap.